# Vuex - How to clear one element in store

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm not trying to clear the ENTIRE store, just one element in the `state`. How can I do that and keep reactivity?

This is my entire `state`:

```
const state = {
  products: {},
  productCount: null,
  emailProducts: { "0":
    { 
        "productTitle": "", 
        "productId": "", 
        "productImage": "",
        "productImageWidth": "",
        "productPosition": ""
    }
  }
};
```

And I JUST want to reset `emailProducts` back to this original state.

I have this as a `mutation`

```
zeroOutEmailProducts: (state) => {
  state.emailProducts = {}
}
```

And then this is my action:

```
resetEmailProducts: ({ commit }) => {
  commit('zeroOutEmailProducts')
},
```

But when I call `resetEmailProducts` it doesn't reset back to nothing..

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are falling into Vue's reactivity caveats. Vue cannot listen to key addition or removal, which is why you need to use [`Vue.set`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set) or [`Vue.delete`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-delete)

You can try to simply replace

```
state.emailProducts = {}
```

with

```
Vue.set(state, "emailProducts", {})
```

And if that doesn't work, delete all the keys one by one

```
Object.keys(state.emailProducts).forEach(key => 
  Vue.delete(state.emailProduct, key)
)
```

You can read more about reactivity caveats here : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Comment: wow.. this for some reason isn't working either.. @Seblor weird

Comment: Can you add more code in your question ? At least the component that is using the store and calling the action.

Comment: Hey @Seblor.. nope it was my fault, your solution was spot on! Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

There seems works:

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    products: {},
    productCount: null,
    emailProducts: { "0":
      { 
          "productTitle": "", 
          "productId": "", 
          "productImage": "",
          "productImageWidth": "",
          "productPosition": ""
      }
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    zeroOutEmailProducts: (state) => {
      state.emailProducts = {}
    }
  },
  actions: {
    resetEmailProducts: ({ commit }) => {
      commit('zeroOutEmailProducts')
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  computed: {
    ...Vuex.mapState({
      emailProducts: state => state.emailProducts
    })
  },
  methods: {
    clearWithUnnecessaryAction() {
      store.dispatch('resetEmailProducts')
    },
    clearWithMutation() {
      store.commit('zeroOutEmailProducts')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.1.3/vuex.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="clearWithUnnecessaryAction">clearWithUnnecessaryAction</button>
  <button @click="clearWithMutation">clearWithMutation</button>
  <pre>{{ emailProducts }}</pre>
</div>
```